# Cannot send email from server heroku using spring javamail

Tags: java, spring, email, heroku, gmail

I tried to send Email from *Heroku*, using *Spring javamail*, but got error.

My code:

```
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("mailService")
public class JavaMailerServiceImpl {

    private MailSender mailSender;
    public JavaMailerServiceImpl(JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body){
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
        mailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

Beans:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="587"/>
    <property name="username" value="**********@gmail.com"/>
    <property name="password" value="********"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And controller:

```
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailerServiceImpl mailService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendEmail(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String recipientAddress = request.getParameter("recipient");
        String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
        String message = request.getParameter("message");
        mailService.sendMail(recipientAddress,subject,message);
    }`
```

At localhost:8080 and localhost:5000, test completed successfully, but on heroku server I have exception:

> Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 j4sm53975482wjg.20 - gsmtp

I performed all recommendations from google. Can you help me solve this problem. Maybe link or something like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devcenter heroku said:

> The Heroku platform itself doesn’t provide an email service - but instead provides add-ons that act as backing services - that can be attached to your app to provide the service.
>
> Consult the Heroku Add-ons marketplace for an appropriate email service that matches your requirements.

[source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp)

Comment: it works...thank you..im able to send mails now using heroku

Comment: So how did you send email via gmail spring?Can you explain bit more

Comment: If really - at that moment, I didn't know about gmail spring. But I think - it would not work too, on servers heroku. Reason - guys from google to much care about safety. Code in question work correct with yahoo on heroku servers

Answer (score 8):

I solved this activating **DisplayUnlockCaptcha** :

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Also activating the **Lesssecureapps**

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

And these are the properties :

```
#Mail properties
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=--
spring.mail.password=--
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.debug=true
spring.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Comment: I don't know who you are or what you do, but you kind sir have just saved my life, many, many thanks

Comment: A pleasure, happy coding ;)

Comment: Won't be possible anymore because `To protect your account, Google will no longer support the use of third-party applications and devices that allow you to sign in to your Google Account with your username and password as of May 30, 2022.`.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Hawklike feel free to update my answer

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Can't edit (the queue is full), so I created an answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55620993/9723204) by Skizo-ozᴉʞS is correct, but as of **May 30, 2022**, Google **will no longer support** the use of third-party applications and devices that allow you to sign in to your Google Account with your **username and password**.

However, there is an easy solution provided by Google.

Instead of a password, input an **app password** generated by Google. Firstly, go to the settings and enable `2-Step Verification`.

[image]

Then click on the `App passwords`.

[image]

You should see the App passwords screen. *App passwords let you sign in to your Google Account from apps on devices that don't support 2-Step Verification*. Select `Mail` as the app and then select a device. In my case, I chose `Other`, because I want to deploy my application to the cloud.

[image]

Once done, click on the `GENERATE` button. You will see your generated app password.

[image]

Just copy the password and replace the previous password in your email sending service with the generated one. You won't be able to see the password again though.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

This is my setting with my app running on Heroku, it worked:

```
#  sparkpost.com SMTP server:
mail.host=smtp.sparkpostmail.com
mail.port=587
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=587
mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
mail.smtp.ssl.enable=false
#mail.smtp.debug=true
mail.username=xxxx
mail.password=xxxx
```