# Spring – Sending E-mail via Gmail SMTP server produces org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException on OpenSuse linux

Tags: java, spring

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
<property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<property name="port" value="587" />
<property name="username" value="username" />
<property name="password" value="password" />

<property name="javaMailProperties">
   <props>
          <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
          <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
       </props>
</property>
```

and the main part of the exception:

22:16:09,917 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-6) UT005023: Exception handling request to /General/registration: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 
534-5.7.14 fuwgWFw3iqh4Y7e4HW99FULVKU7Df24ZrQpr-yK56binPTeeYX6cU9uUzVa86wMv25A_ej
534-5.7.14 N7yGgIzi0XMpWXZMkyDpCnDnnRWkynYB3jIsZgeH8YAH7yG18QUuDgoUBV4qt3FLsQ7peM
534-5.7.14 HJiK-1EjtiiO7DRGT1LKdlRbC5p52sEGD4OQuX_5zeA8kCIzASbzusaIcb3q_LaHSXehSt
534-5.7.14 ZNzKtavmee7WdOzt0yAgSSn1OrM8Q> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 t16sm18972891wra.44 - gsmtp

Answer (score 0):

To send mail using Gmail SMTP, need to change your account setting to allow less secure apps. Login into your gmail accout then follow the link below to change your gmail account setting to send mail using your apps and program. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Allow less secure apps: ON

Comment: Allow less secure apps is ON, but I get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting contacted by text or email about suspicious activity then your details are fine and this should work: Activating Gmails DisplayUnlockCaptcha and Lesssecureapps https://stackoverflow.com/a/55620993/12234839